# Is [repr(C)] propagated to child members?

Tags: rust

I have a struct:

```
struct A {
    names: Vec<String>,
}
```

And another struct:

```
#[repr(C)]
struct B {
    pub a: A,
}
```

Does this make `A` also have the `repr(C)` annotation? Would it be correct to pass such structure to C code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answers are:

1. No
2. No

`#[repr(C)]` doesn't make structures "safe to FFI", it guarantees that the in-memory representation will be as is and the compiler will not try to optimize them for space/efficiency under the cover. This is accidentally what is also needed for safe FFI.

Answer (score 2):

It certainly isn't safe to pass your structure to C code.  There are some caveats in the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/other-reprs.html), including:

- > DSTs, tuples, and tagged unions are not a concept in C and as such are never FFI safe

  You have no guarantee about whether any of these are in the `Vec`.  Also, since `Vec` is opaque.
- > If the type would have any drop flags, they will still be added"

  Again, `Vec` may have some.

And in any case, for it to make any sense at the receiving C code, you need to declare your struct in C as well; and since `Vec<String>` is opaque, there isn't a reasonable way to do so.

I think the reason for having `#[repr(C)]` is to reproduce data to match an existing C API you want to interoperate with; not to somehow directly expose internal Rust types to C.